# Could someone explain these wiring diagram symbols please?

Tags: electrical, exhaust-fan

This is for a bathroom ceiling fan.

[image]

I recognise the pull cord switch. It's the two middle symbols I'm not sure about.

1. The square one on the right. Is that just a switch? Something like this: https://www.screwfix.com/p/british-general-13a-double-pole-switched-fused-connection-unit-white/86116
2. The round one on the left. Is that a three way junction box? What's with the spiral symbol between Ls and N?

I'd be very grateful if someone could provide links to appropriate components that would match those two parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Not quite, it is a [*three* pole fan-isolator](https://www.screwfix.com/p/mk-logic-plus-1-gang-10a-3-pole-fan-isolator-switch-white/12319).
2. Kinda

   1. As Harpur wrote - this is the ceiling rose.
   2. It's your light bulb.

I have a couple of these but I've never needed to open them up.

Comment: The light bulb! Of course! Ha ha. Ok, thank you, I'm planning on wiring it up separately to the light because I don't want it to come on whenever the light is on, but your explanation makes me confident I can work out how to do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

2 is your lamp's ceiling rose.   A standard 3/3/2 splice won't quite be enough because both always-hot and switched-hot are being carried onward to the fan, it's unusual for both to be carried onward at once.

2b is your lamp.